# Clone, filter and plonk HTML node with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try to clone subnode of HTML, filter the clone and plonk it elsewhere in the page.

I try this:

```js
var emailTemplate = $("#email-post")[0];
$("#tempStoreEmailTemplate").val(emailTemplate.outerHTML);
$(tempStoreEmailTemplate).find('.num6:hidden').remove();
$("#iframe-textarea").val(tempStoreEmailTemplate.val)//.outerHTML
```

```html
<div id="tempStoreEmailTemplate" hidden></div>
```

I tried both `tempStoreEmailTemplate.val` and `tempStoreEmailTemplate.outerHTML` in the last line. `.outerHTML` shows this text

```html
<div id="tempStoreEmailTemplate" hidden=""></div>
```

`.val` shows nothing.

The expected result would be to see the textual representation of the modified subnode. Do you know what is wrong?

---

HTML nesting with `#email-post` looks like this:

```
                <h4>Email Preview</h4>

                        <!-- Card -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="email-post">
   <head>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to do with how you are storing the temporary block - using `.val()` puts it in the value attribute, which is useful in input fields... Not so much in `div`s. If, however, you were to append the temporary block:

```
var emailTemplate = $("#email-post") //If you are using the ID tag correctly, this selector will only retrieve one element, you don't need to specify [0]
$("#tempStoreEmailTemplate").append($(emailTemplate))
```

It places a copy of the entire sub-tree matched by `#email-post` into the element matched by `#tempStoreEmailTemplate` as a child; for instance:

```
<div id="tempStoreEmailTemplate" hidden>
    <div id="email-post">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

This allows you to do your filter:

```
$('#tempStoreEmailTemplate').find('.num6:hidden').remove();
```

And then to place the filtered HTML into your textarea, you can just do this:

```
$("#iframe-textarea").val($('#tempStoreEmailTemplate').html())
```

Which would put the following into your textarea:

```
<div id="email-post">
    ...
</div>
```

EDIT to add: You may have to alter how you're hiding `#tempStoreEmailTemplate`, if the current solution doesn't work then you may have to alter the div to:

```
<div id="tempStoreEmailTemplate" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, on the second line I got this error: `jquery-1.12.4.js:6272 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.`

Comment: Apologies @János - I've edited a tweak in on line 2 and added another potential requirement

Comment: I did the tweak in the second line, it raise same error `The new child element contains the parent. ` Don't you think problem is that the nesting tag is not a DIV but a HTML with a `<!DOCTYPE`. I filled it end of the question.

Comment: ahh, I modified second line with `.outerHTML` like this `$("#tempStoreEmailTemplate").append($(emailTemplate).outerHTML)`, and that works now, but I still has an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69026433/why-do-i-not-see-html-content-in-textarea-but-only-object-htmldivelement