# Why do I not see HTML content in TextArea but only "[object HTMLDivElement]"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a HTML nested into HTML. I would clone it, modify it, and paste to an TextArea.

But I see at the end of the steps in TextArea only this: `[object HTMLDivElement]`

What do I miss?

jQuery steps:

```
var emailTemplate = $("#email-post")[0]
$("#tempStoreEmailTemplate").append($(emailTemplate).outerHTML)
$(tempStoreEmailTemplate).find('.num6:hidden').remove();
$("#iframe-textarea").val(tempStoreEmailTemplate)//.outerHTML .html()
```

I tried commented options.

This is how HTML nesting looks:

```
                <h4>Email Preview</h4>

                        <!-- Card -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="email-post">
   <head>
```

and here is the `textArea`:

```
        <div class="col-md-6 pb-4">
            <div class="card p-3">
                <h4>Generated Code</h4>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="iframe-textarea" rows="8"></textarea>
```

**I would show in textarea a html email template** which user can copy paste.

Comment: Can you show us more HTML code? Where is `<textarea>` ?

Comment: added the part with textarea

Comment: Unless this is some kind of a template, nesting HTMLs doesn't work. It's not clear what you want to show in the [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#technical_summary), but it can contain plain text only, no elements at all.

Comment: I would show a textual html email template  in textarea  which user can copy paste.

Comment: Why do you want the user to see the full HTML block for the emails? Surely you'd be better off giving them a WYSIWYG editor? Plus, you don't actually need to feed email packages a full html document - they wrap it up themselves.

Comment: The question is more like the how, and not the why. :) I would show raw email content in a textarea.